# Defining a nested racket macro with access to surrounding variables

Tags: macros, racket

I have a macro that extends the racket syntax, and at some point accepts a sequence of bog standard racket expressions. This looks something like this, the relevant syntax variable being `body`:

```
(syntax-parse stx
  [(_ some-id:id
      body:expr ...+)
```

This macro generates a racket class with a generated method like so:

```
#'(<class stuff>
   (define/public (some-id some-formal-parameter)
     body ...)
```

As I said the `body` is plain racket code, except for one expression that can be used exclusively in the body, for example:

```
(define-syntax-rule (tweet identifier value)
  (send this publish-tweet (quote identifier) value))
```

But this does not allow me to use `some-formal-parameter` because it is not defined. Is there some proper way in which I can define something that can exclusively be used in the body, and can still bind to variables in the context after expansion? Maybe via a [splicing syntax class](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-specifying.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._define-splicing-syntax-class%29%29)? Reusability is a big bonus, since this "type of body" may exists in multiple (similar) macros.

Some code for testing:

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (define-something stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ some-id:id
        body:expr ...+)
     #'(define some-id
         (new
          (class object%
            (super-new)
            (define/public (displ arg)
              (displayln arg))
            (define/public (tick some-formal-parameter) 
              body ...))))]))

(define-syntax-rule (tweet value)
  (send this displ value))


(define-something derp
  (define a 'not-derp)
  (tweet a))

(send derp tick 'derp)
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but from what I can understand, it sounds like syntax parameters is the way to implement it. If you can post what your expected before-and-afters are, I can try to cook something up. :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. "Thinking with macros" is hard to get into. There is so much to learn, so much to know, so much you have to know. I am reading a [paper](http://scheme2011.ucombinator.org/papers/Barzilay2011.pdf) about syntax parameters and it looks like this could solve it. I don't know if it solves it in a good way, but I will try some stuff out and report back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reformulate the original question now that I know (and can answer) what I wanted to ask: how can I define a macro that can only be used in a certain context (for me: in the body of a method of a racket class), and how can I use dynamically bound variables. In the original code above: when using the expression `(tweet a)` not only do I want the value of `a`, but also the value of `some-formal-parameter` which is bound in the context of the code where the tweet macro is expanded (not where it is defined).

Chris Jester-Young kindly pointed me to syntax parameters, which indeed seem to solve both the issue of dynamic binding and "can only be used in certain contexts". A [paper](http://barzilay.org/misc/stxparam.pdf) by Eli Barzilay, Ryan Culpepper, and Matthew Flatt helped me understand syntax parameters.

With respect to the original example code I posted, this is the solution I have come up with:

```
#lang racket

(require
  racket/stxparam
  (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax-parameter tweet
  (lambda (stx)
    (raise-syntax-error 'tweet "use of an actor keyword outside of the body of an actor" stx)))

(define-syntax (define-something stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ some-id:id
        body:expr ...+)
     #'(define some-id
         (new
          (class object%
            (super-new)

            (define/public (tick some-formal-parameter)
              (syntax-parameterize
               ([tweet
                 (syntax-rules ()
                   [(_ value)
                    (begin (displayln some-formal-parameter)
                           (displayln value))])])
               body ...)
              ))))]))

(define-something derp
  (define a 'not-derp)
  (tweet a))

(send derp tick 'derp)
```

The three key points of attention are the following.

1. Because of the definition of the `tweet` macro, whenever it is used outside of the context of a `syntax-parametrize` statement (that changes the definition of `tweet`) it will throw an appropriate error.
2. In the body of the public method `tick` of our class we change thedefinition of `tweet` to a macro that matches a pattern of the form `(_ value)` (which is the value we supply to `tweet`)
3. The tweet macro can expand to something that both uses the bound value `value`, *and* the value of `some-formal-parameter`, whatever that may be.

I do not know if this is the proper way to deal with such a situation, but it seems good.

Comment: Good solution! However, you probably noticed that you can't refer to `some-formal-parameter` within the body of `define-something`, because they're in different lexical scopes. Maybe that's ok, but if you did want to be able to do that, the solution would be another syntax parameter for `some-formal-parameter`. That's because there are now two things that you want to be available within the body of `define-something`.

Comment: For the particular problem I had it is indeed not a problem that the body of `define-something` cannot use `some-formal-parameter`. In fact, it is a parameter that the body should not be aware of, so the fact that it is not in the lexical scope is actually great. Thank you for your comment. It's a good validation for my solution, and when others stumble on this question  they might find the insight useful :)